# Android 4.4 mediaplayer leaks threads

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am developing an application which is designed to display rotating media content including images, videos, web sites etc.

The application has been working correctly on Android 4.2 but when trying it on Android 4.4 I noticed that it would execute for about a 24 hours and then quit from a memory allocation exception.  It uses a VideoView which is created to play the video and then removed.  I have tried using a single VideoView which is not recreated but that does not make a difference.

I have determined that the probable cause for this is a thread leak in the MediaPlayer object when playing videos.  After placing lots of logging code into the application and collecting the logs I notice that the thread count is continually growing and that there are numerous threads still running the android.media.MediaPlayer$1.run function.  See excerpt below which is a thread dump performed by the program and is showing in excess of 302 threads for this application after many hours of operation.

```
[4471]2014/12/02 06:53:04:DEBUG:logThreads:300:Trace information for the thread Thread[Thread-1662,5,main]
[4471]2014/12/02 06:53:04:DEBUG:logThreads:300:Thread status RUNNABLE alive true
[4471]2014/12/02 06:53:04:DEBUG:logThreads:300:android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
[4471]2014/12/02 06:53:04:DEBUG:logThreads:300:android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
[4471]2014/12/02 06:53:04:DEBUG:logThreads:300:android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
[4471]2014/12/02 06:53:04:DEBUG:logThreads:300:android.media.MediaPlayer$1.run(MediaPlayer.java:1491)
[4471]2014/12/02 06:53:04:DEBUG:logThreads:300:java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
[4471]2014/12/02 06:53:04:DEBUG:logThreads:301:Trace information for the thread Thread[Thread-1469,5,main]
[4471]2014/12/02 06:53:04:DEBUG:logThreads:301:Thread status RUNNABLE alive true
[4471]2014/12/02 06:53:04:DEBUG:logThreads:301:android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
[4471]2014/12/02 06:53:04:DEBUG:logThreads:301:android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
[4471]2014/12/02 06:53:04:DEBUG:logThreads:301:android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
[4471]2014/12/02 06:53:04:DEBUG:logThreads:301:android.media.MediaPlayer$1.run(MediaPlayer.java:1491)
[4471]2014/12/02 06:53:04:DEBUG:logThreads:301:java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
[4471]2014/12/02 06:53:04:DEBUG:logThreads:302:Trace information for the thread Thread[Thread-1636,5,main]
[4471]2014/12/02 06:53:04:DEBUG:logThreads:302:Thread status RUNNABLE alive true
[4471]2014/12/02 06:53:04:DEBUG:logThreads:302:android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
[4471]2014/12/02 06:53:04:DEBUG:logThreads:302:android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
[4471]2014/12/02 06:53:04:DEBUG:logThreads:302:android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
[4471]2014/12/02 06:53:04:DEBUG:logThreads:302:android.media.MediaPlayer$1.run(MediaPlayer.java:1491)
[4471]2014/12/02 06:53:04:DEBUG:logThreads:302:java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

This issue does not seem to happen in Android 4.2 with the same program.  It looks like the MediaPlayer object is not stopping the thread when it starts a new video and creating a new one.  I have tried keeping a single MediaPlayer instance as well as removing and creating a fresh one each time but the results are the same.

The calling function is here.  In the debugging process I copied the source code for the VideoView class and called it MSMVideoView to try a few things with that code.

```
public void playVideo(final String fileName) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            FileLog.d("MediaPlayVideo","Playing video "+fileName);
            createVideoView();
            final MSMVideoView v= getVideoView();
            // make sure to clear the mediaplayer
            if (v != null) {
                try {
                    playerInfo="NO_INFO";
                    playing_error_count=0;

                    v.stopPlayback();
                    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    v.setVideoPath(getMediaSchedulerService().getFileManager().getFileLocalPath(fileName));
                    v.setOnCompletionListener( new OnCompletionListener() {                     
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            try {
                                v.stopPlayback();
                                playing=false;
                                WebView myWebView = getWrapperWebView();
                                myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:onVideoComplete()");
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                FileLog.d("MediaPlayVideo","Exception in all to onVideoComplete "+e.getMessage());                                  
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    v.setOnInfoListener(new OnInfoListener() {                      
                        @Override
                        public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                            switch(what) {
                            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_UNKNOWN: playerInfo = "UNKNOWN";
                            break;
                            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BAD_INTERLEAVING: playerInfo="BAD_INTERLEAVING";
                            break;
                            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_END: playerInfo="BUFFERING_END";
                            break;
                            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START: playerInfo="BUFFERING_START";
                            break;
                            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_METADATA_UPDATE: playerInfo="METADATA_UPDATE";
                            break;
                            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_NOT_SEEKABLE: playerInfo="NOT_SEEKABLE";
                            break;
                            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_VIDEO_RENDERING_START: playerInfo="VIDEO_RENDERING_START";
                            break;
                            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_VIDEO_TRACK_LAGGING: playerInfo="VIDEO_TRACK_LAGGING";
                            break;
                            default:
                                playerInfo="UNDEFINED";
                                break;                          
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    v.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {                        
                        @Override
                        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                            try {
                                FileLog.e(LOG_TAG,"Error Playing " + fileName + " error " + what + " extra " + extra);
                                playing=false;
                                mp.reset();
                                WebView myWebView = getWrapperWebView();
                                myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:onVideoError()");

                                if (currentElement != null) {
                                    CallExternalUrl(getApplicationServer()+"/logerror.php?mediaid="+URLEncoder.encode(currentElement.getId().toString())+"&error="+URLEncoder.encode("Error Playing " + currentElement.getFileName() + " error " + what + " extra " + extra));
                                } else {
                                    CallExternalUrl(getApplicationServer()+"/logerror.php?mediaid="+URLEncoder.encode(currentElement.getId().toString())+"&error="+URLEncoder.encode("Error Playing unknown - error " + what + " extra " + extra));                                 
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                FileLog.d("MediaPlayVideo","Exception in onError "+e.getMessage());                                 
                            }
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
                    v.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            try {
                                mp.start();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                FileLog.e("MediaPlayVideo","onPrepared:Error " + e.getMessage());                                   
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    playing=true;
                    currentStartTime=System.currentTimeMillis();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    FileLog.e("MediaPlayVideo","Error " + e.getMessage());
                }
            } else {
                FileLog.d("MediaPlayVideo","Cannot find R.id.displayVideoView");
            }
            setBusy(false);
        }
    });
}

public MSMVideoView getVideoView() {
    return videoView;
}


public void createVideoView() {
    if (videoView == null) {
        try {
            RelativeLayout contentLayout=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_layout);
            videoView = new MSMVideoView(this);
            videoView.setId(VIDEO_VIEW_ID);

            FileLog.d("createVideoView",String.format("Adding video to layout"));
            contentLayout.addView(videoView);

            FileLog.d("createVideoView",String.format("Moving video to %d,%d,%d,%d",getImageLeft(),getImageTop(),getImageRight(),getImageBottom()));
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(getImageRight()-getImageLeft(), getImageBottom()-getImageTop());
            params.leftMargin=getImageLeft();
            params.topMargin=getImageTop();
            videoView.setLayoutParams(params);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            FileLog.e("createVideoView","Error:" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I am wondering if there is anything that I am doing which could cause this.  I have posted a bug report to the android open source project as well (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81471)

Thanks in advance for any advice

Comment: I wanted to provide an update for this.  This problem seems to present itself on a Minix X8 running 4.4.2 but does not seem to be an issue on a Note 4 on 4.4.4.  I think the issue may be fixed in the newer release which I will try and obtain for the X8.

Comment: Another update.  This issue does indeed seem to be resolved by the most recent firmware for the X8-H which is available from Minix.  I found it in the forums under the post http://www.minixforum.com/threads/official-002-firmware.2413/